# Get my C# application working on Mac OS X

Tags: c#, macos

i was wondering how i convert my C# app to be used on Mac OS x. I don't know if this is even possible. If it's possible what's the tools to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a .NET framework complete with compiler called [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) that will allow you to compile your C# code on the Mac and Linux platforms. However note that not all C# code written on Windows is Mono compliant. Namely anything you write that refers to the Microsoft.* namespaces will not exist in Mono and will need to be rewritten using a new library. Download their development tools, and give compiling a whirl to see how much work porting the app will be, also note that the mono compliant version should still compile on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono%3aOSX) is a framework which supports .NET apps on some Unix based platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Silverlight programs in OS X.